# Reallocation Event Count high threshold

Tags: hard-drive, defragment

I've bought recently a WD black, and I've made a SMART check on it, these are the values : 
http://prntscr.com/3t6szr
The rellocation event count worries me. The HDD works pretty neat tho.

Installed it 4 days ago. 
Also I've got a big fragmentation percentage, doing a full defragmentation right now.

Should I worry about this value or not ? Thanks

Comment: Look at current and worst. The "danger zone" is when they drop below the threshold, though with reallocation and pending even a slight drop can indicate issues. But yours is perfect.

Comment: thanks a lot, I've been worrying a bit ( I have warranty, but the idea of few more days for a new replacement was killing me ). You can post it as an answer I guess so I can rate hit. Thanks